# "Http 500: Unable to launch ideviceinstaller" error while building cordova apps on ios

Tags: ios, cordova

When I tried to build cordova apps on my mac. I've set up remotebuild and it is working fine until I wanted to build on remote device.
This is the error I received:

> Http 500: Unable to launch ideviceinstaller.
>       Please ensure that homebrew is installed and try running "brew install ideviceinstaller"

I've installed ideviceinstaller but it still couldn't build. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide more info on what command you are trying to execute and framework details

Comment: I'm debugging visual studio solution remotely on an ios device.

Comment: You need to install ideviceinstaller on the Mac by using "brew install ideviceinstaller" in terminal. You may also have to install webkit debug proxy if required using brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy. Hope it helps